# JSON POST request on Heroku loses data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, node.js, heroku

I'm sending a JSON POST from a node.js server to my Heroku app running Rails, but the Rails app doesn't get the data. The request goes through, but there is no data.

Everything works locally, but not on Heroku?

Here is the code from my node.js:

```
var post_data = datastring;
var post_options = {
  host: '####.herokuapp.com',
  port: '80',
  path: '/bulk_readings.json',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}
```

Anyone that have seen this problem before?

Comment: What do you see in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by my self.

In the node.js I had

```
post_req.write(post_data);
```

It should be:

```
post_req.end(post_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first culprit would be to check out the header files, different rack servers apply different filters to determine what the request is.

Try adding `Accept: application/json` to your request headers

Comment: Tried that now, that dont change anything. I can get the post-request working from PostMan, so I might think it is at the node.js where the problem is.